# Should I Stick to 32bit or 64bit Types for Fixed-Point Number Class?

Tags: c#, int, 32bit-64bit, long-integer, fixed-point

I've been developing a game in C# which currently uses floating points for some calculations and arithmetic. This game will feature networking functionality and a basic replay system which keeps track of inputs and basic player actions over time. I think these features require me to have every important core mechanic be deterministic. Due to the supposed indeterministic attributes of floating point numbers, I have gone through some resources about fixed-point numbers in order to provide myself with an alternative to floating point.

I understand many of the core concepts of fixed-point due to a variety of very well documented online resources on the matter. However, I'm unsure of whether or not I should use a 32bit type (int) or 64bit type (long) for the raw-value of the fixed-point class.

I would like to have the following basic features for my class:

- Pass a float, double or int and convert it to a fixed-point value.
- Addition, Subtraction, Division, Multiplication against values of types fixed-point, int, float and double.

My assumption is that it would be best to use a long as it will give me more decimal accuracy, but I am worried about potential roadblocks that may come along the way. For example, would using a long provide issues when targeting 32bit or running on 32bit machines? Are ints ultimately more compatible than long when it comes to potential hardware configurations? Because games are performance heavy, is there a large performance loss when switching from float to long based fixed-point numbers?

It seems like a silly question, but I guess I'm wondering if I should use types based off the lowest common denominator of cpu architecture that I expect my program to run on or are these concerns typically handled by the compiler during compilation? Will linux or mac osx handle long calculations differently than a windows machine?

Comment: Int's in C# are always 32-bit and long's in C# are always 64-bit. This is a feature of the language and the CLR. Processors can be 32-bit or 64-bit and this is just a measure of how much data it can process at once. It is irrelevant of data types in the language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type you use is irrelevant, with regards to the platform, as types are types are types, in C#.  In other words, a long is always 64 bits, no matter what platform you're on.  It's a guarantee of C#.

However, the real problem is going to be precision and scale.. When doing fixed-point math, you're going to have to pick the precision you want to use.  That's an easy problem.  What's not easy is scaling.  If you have numbers that will exceed the maximum value of your chosen type (don't forget to include the decimals in this consideration), then you're broken out of the gate.

Have you looked into the `decimal` type?

`decimal` is still a floating-point type, but it is floating-point decimal, rather than IEEE754 binary floating-point, and thus is capable of representing any base-10 number you throw at it, so long as it fits in the scale and precision of the `decimal` type.

See these links for information on the `decimal` type:

- [C# In Depth:Decimal](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Decimal.aspx)
- [MSDN C# decimal reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx)

`decimal` comes with some performance considerations, however, and may not be the best choice for a game, if performance is critical.  For a simple 2D scroller, you'd be fine, but it's probably not ideal for anything beyond that.

Comment: I've heard that the decimal type can be slow which isn't exactly ideal for game operations. From: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/14776/how-are-deterministic-games-possible-in-the-face-of-floating-point-non-determini

Comment: It does come with some performance considerations, but a custom fixed-point class is going to come with plenty of its own, as well.  Depending on the complexity of the application, it may not be worth bothering with a manual implementation of a solved problem.

Answer (score 2):

The results will be exactly the same across all targets. Integer math is nice like that, you can really rely on it to be the same all the same time.

Using a long will be slower though, particularly when targeting 32bit machines but also on 64bit machines. While adding ints and adding longs takes the same time on a 64bit machine (if it's actually 64bit code), doing a fixpoint multiplication requires some extra code if you don't have a type that's twice as big. 64bit division has the same problem. Of course on 32bit machines, 64bit operations are emulated using multiple 32bit operations, so they are inherently slightly slower there.

On the other hand, you may need the extra precision sometimes. In the end you may need both a 32bit fixpoint type and a 64bit one, or even multiple of those with differently positioned radix points.